# Specific counterexample involving convergence of integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I have proven that if $X$ is a measurable space and $f, f_n: X \to [0,\infty]$ are measurable functions with $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $\lim \int f_n = \int f < \infty$, then $\int_{E}f_n \to \int_{E}f$ for all measurable $E \subseteq X$.

Is there a counterexample that breaks this statement if $\lim \int f_n = \int f = \infty$? I'm struggling to see any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X = \mathbb R$ with Lebesgue measure; $f_n(x) = f(x) = 1$ for $x < 0$;
for $x > 0$, $f(x) = 0$ while $f_n(x) = 1$ for $n < x < n+1$, $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise.
$E = [0,\infty)$.